# single simple pole, $e^{i\theta } \frac{1-\overline{z_0}z}{z-z_0}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $D= \big\{z:|z|\leq 1\big\}$,  $|z_{0}|\in D$.  A function $f(z)$ such that
>
> 1).$f(z)$ is analytic on $D\setminus \{z_0\}$;
>
> 2).$f$ has  a single simple pole  at $z_0$ ;
>
> 3). $f(z)\ne 0$, $|z|<1$; and
>
> 4). If $|z|=1$, then $|f(z)|=1$.
>
> show that  $f(z)=e^{i\theta } \frac{1-\overline{z_0}z}{z-z_0}$.

well,  Can we use Maximum modulus principle to $F(z)=f(z)\cfrac{z-z_0}{1-\bar z_0z}$? How about Schwarz's lemma?

I'd be very grateful for any help

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Clearly $w=\frac{z-z_0}{1-\overline{z_0}z}$ maps $D\to D$ and $z_0\to 0$ and $z=\frac{w+z_0}{1+\overline{z_0}w}$. Define
$$ F(w)=\frac{1}{f(\frac{w+z_0}{1+\overline{z_0}w})}. $$
Now you can use Schwarz's lemma and you will get it.

Comment: $F(0)=0$? thanks

Comment: @ziangchen, I changed a little.

Comment: Can we use Maximum modulus principle to $f(z)\cfrac{z-z_0}{1-\bar z_0z}$ ? Thanks

Comment: @ziangchen, you can use. But for this problem, Schwarz's lemma is enough.